# How to recalculate bone transforms/constraints to originate from armature origin point?

Tags: python, animation, scripting, armature, add-on

I'm trying to make an export script, and I need all the exported bones to be positioned at the armature's origin point. The trouble is that I would like to be able to position the bones anywhere in the scene so that the animation process is more efficient. While for me it is quite doable if I only work with individual bones, the complicated part for me is that I also want to be able to add constraints and other bones it would be linked to. (These would be discarded in the export process)

[Here is a link to a blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q__Alg4CzQ_4ODWyA9P5zySHnx1U4p3Q/view?usp=sharing). In that I have two rectangles which are each applied to a bone. "BoneTransform" has a bone which is located some place other than the origin point, while "CursorTransform" has a bone which is located at the origin point. My basic desire is to be able to animate with an armature set up like BoneTransform, but for the export to output the transformation data of CursorTransform with the added twist of constraints and what not, so please address this in any answers which you might post.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for myself. However, it regrettably does use bpy.ops. If anyone has a solution which does not use bpy.ops I'd gladly take a look at that answer.

[Here is the blend file for anyone who wants to take a look.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cCtrB7Y8hPplZcz-9K6z-GIzDrA11ynI/view?usp=sharing)